# Not receiving the JSON Object from server validation Google reCapthca V3

Tags: php, api, response, contact-form, recaptcha-v3

I am trying to verify a user's response to a reCAPTCHA challenge from my application's backend.
Please can you advise me if I Have inserted the code below in to the right section of the contact form to verify a user's response to a reCaptcha challenge.

*Note!* I am seeing the generated users's response token in the console!

This is the contact form code

````
```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
empty($_POST['email'])     ||
empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
empty($_POST['message'])   ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "No arguments Provided!";
return false;
}

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com';
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:  \n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
````

Here is the the server side validation code for verifying the users response, I am using (Google V3 reCaptcha)

````
```
foreach ($_POST a $key => $value) {
           echo 'key: '.$key.' value: '.$value.'<br />';
        }

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['recaptcha_response'])) {
           $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
           $recaptcha_secret = 'SECRET_KEY';
           $recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];
           $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url.'?secret='.$recaptcha_secret.'&=response='.$recaptcha_response);
           $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);

           foreach ($recaptcha as $key => $value) {
              echo 'object: '.$key.' value: '.$value.'<br />';
           }

           if($recaptcha->score >= 0.5) { https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3
              echo 'verification succesful';
           } else {
              echo 'verification failed';
              exit;
           }
        }

return true;         
?>
```
````

Have I placed the code in the right section of the contact form?